# Measuring distance between frequency data in R

Tags: r, math, statistics, distance

I have a group of genes where for each gene I calculate the frequency of a set of motifs (substrings), each motif has a weight corresponding to the correlation between the motif frequency and the gene abundance or expression.

I want to calculate the similarity between these genes based on the weighted motifs frequency. In other words, I want a distance score that can be calculated between frequency data and also take into account the weights/importance of each motif frequency.

```
Gene1 = c(11.26971112,0.26609964,0.23126772,0.27460510,0.03523694,0.02430134,
           0.01336574,0.01093560,0.01458080,0.06439854)


Gene2 = c(10.363039630,0.219438117,0.300683371,0.231586940,0.022779043,0.020501139,
           0.009111617,0.018223235,0.002277904,0.029612756)  

Weights = c(0.19942123,0.06118163,0.19720853,0.14889052,0.19409911,0.0904736,
            0.04931893,0.06494762,0.04148397,0.07337904)
```

I want to calculate the distance between Gene1 and Gene2 where Weights represent the weights of each frequency (column) in the genes

Comment: Can you use `((Gene1-Gene2)*Weights)^2`?

Comment: I already tried that as my first candidate method, but the results weren't very accurate, I mean the closest gene according to this distance score isn't actually the closest one in the database

Comment: closest gene is the one with the closest sequence, however, I don't have the full sequence for all the genes but I have the frequency for all of them as shown in the example

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, `sum((Gene1-Gene2)^2*Weights)`, but perhaps you need to do a little modeling to find a distance metric that works well for the subset of genes for which you do have full sequences and then apply that to that for which you don't.